# about Func.repeatN

Tags: .net, f#

There is code in Expert F# like this :

```
// Perform a CPU-intensive operation on the image.
    pixels |> Func.repeatN processImageRepeats (Array.map (fun b -> b + 1uy))
```

what is the use of Func.repeatN? 
it seems its already gone. Is there a function which replace Func.repeatN?

For more information:
I did search it on google, there is one appear on top but i can't access this web (my keyword is :Func.RepeatN) :
The F# September 2008 Community Technology Preview, 1.9.6.2
stuff.mit.edu/afs/athena.mit.edu/.../README-fsharp.html - 
The Permutation module remains in the PowerPack; Func.*, e.g. Func.repeatN deleted; CompatArray and CompatMatrix modules deleted. ...

Comment: I doesn't seem to exist natively in F#... are you sure it isn't defined in the book?

Comment: nope. It does mentioned in the code but no explanation at all

Answer (score 1):

This is definitely not a standard F# library function.

Unless this is some performance chapter (where the authors just need slower implementation for demonstration purposes), the function should most likely repeatedly apply the specified transformation on the input and then on the result of the previous application. When it reaches zero, it would return the original input unmodified.

The implementation is a simple recursive function:

```
module Func = 
  let rec repeatN count f input = 
    // Repeating less than zero times - return the input
    if count <= 0 then input
    // Otherwise apply the function once and repeat (count - 1) times
    else repeatN (count - 1) f (f input)
```

**EDIT** My original thought (now deleted) was probably wrong (I don't have the book around to check), so this is an improved answer.

Comment: many thanks mr Tomas. your code does work well. But it just a little bit confusing because there are no differences between using repeatN or just using Array.map at the result of the program, the Func.repeatN just make the program become slow

Comment: @Yabert - Oh, on a second thought, I think my original guess was wrong. Instead, the function could just repeatedly call `f`, so writing `repeatN 3 f input` is the same as `f (f (f input))`.

Comment: It's page 371 (of the first edition), just to save you searching if and when you do have the book to hand.